# Will leaving the ducting on the propellers attached to a DIY aircraft give it more thrust?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-performance, propeller, model-aircraft

I'm not sure if its the right place, I have a problem with a flying thingy, and you like flying thingies, don't you?

I will be trying to add some means of propulsion to my friend's styrofoam plane (3ft wingspan, 2-3ft length). I have quite a few computer fans lying around, so I decided to add four (two on each side of the hull) 1W, 2x2 inch fans. Now you don't see a lot of propeller planes with their propellers ducted (well, maybe except for jet engines, but they are a different animal), do you? Now, I heard that ducting equals more efficiency and thrust.

So should I snip the ducting off or let it stay on? I can provide more information if you need it.
[image: big ol fanboye]

Comment: I have a doubt you are going to get any measurable thrust from 4 1W computer fans, shroud or not.

Comment: Ducting does improve efficiency, but this is most notably observed in high performance applications. There is no way ducting a computer fan will make up for the ducts weight. Especially if you are thinking about using the case the fans came in as your duct.

Comment: @RonBeyer What if I stick a rotor (the spinning thing) across the motots shaft, using the motr to make it spin?

Comment: @RonBeyer: [I wouldn't be so sure](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/21917/does-a-1lb-crow-expend-only-7-68-watts-to-fly-at-37-km-h).

Comment: Add a picture. Those fans can be rather heavy and draw a lot of current.

Comment: The brushless motor is optimized for low EMI, not for low weight.

Comment: I did some experiments in the past on the thrust from a pc fan (by simply hanging it above a digital kitchen scale). It's very little, even with the duct attatched. Why not just spend a few bucks (<$1 per propeller) on cheap eBay parts?